# Unable to compile even after including \usepackage {ytablau} as a last \usepackage after downloading texlive-full

Tags: ytableau

While write a instruction in the body of the text,

```
\ytableausetup
{mathmode, boxsize=2em}
\begin{ytableau}
......
\end{ytableau}
```

While compiling, error message appear as

```
> ! LaTeX Error: Environment ytablaue undefined.
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
> <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    
> 
> l.313 \begin{ytablaue} ?
```

How to resolve?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you read the error message, you can see that you have typed `ytablaue` instead of `ytableau` hence the error.

Comment: An obvious answer, but extremely useful. Thanks